# Pandas DataFrame TypeError must be str not int on calling mean for dType object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, mean

I'm working with a dataset using Pandas and python(3) in which I need to get rid of nulls, so that I'm trying to take the mean for that particular column to fill the nulls but got the error below:

> TypeError: must be str, not int

When I call the `.info()` on the DataFrame I got it's data type object as:

`object`

and here's the link for the dataset in case if you want more info:
https://www.kaggle.com/orgesleka/imdbmovies

so, How can I got the mean for `object` and `float64` type of values in my data frame columns?

thanks in advance!

Comment: show us some sample data ? also object means your columns is mixed type with string like

Comment: Also which columns raise the problem

Comment: I have added a link to the dataset.

Comment: Which column you are work with fillna ?

Comment: here are the columns with null values: `wordsintitle`, `imdbrating`, `ratingcount`, `duration`, `year` but I think it sticks on the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built in `.fillna()` method on your column.

So you might do something like this...

```
df['column_of_interest'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column_of_interest'])
my_mean = df['column_of_interest'].dropna().mean()

df['column_of_interest'].fillna(my_mean)
```

You might need to set `inplace=True`, else just go with `df['column_of_interest'] = df['column_of_interest'].fillna(my_mean)` if it doesn't automatically fill the NaNs in place.

Comment: it returns: `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: Are you expecting the column to be numeric? If so, it might be that some values in there are strings instead of floats, in which case you could try `df['column_of_interest'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column_of_interest'])` first, and then try the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when you import the csv file , the sample data using a specific value as null

Quick fix

```
df=pd.read_csv('your.csv',na_values = [ '#N/A', 'NA', 'NULL', 'NaN', 'n/a', 'nan', 'null'])
```

Another fix

```
for x in ['wordsintitle', 'imdbrating', 'ratingcount', 'duration', 'year']: 
    df[x]=pd.to_numeric(df[x],errors='coerce')
```